# Expandable ListView with different child items in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, expandablelistview, listviewitem

any suggestions for how to implement expandable list view with different child views in Xamarin forms. Can anyone please help me for this?

Comment: Putting all your contents in a StatckLayout, you can make use of the IsVisible property of StackLayout to show or hide the StackLayout on Tapped. Want more clarification?

Comment: @OluwasayoBabalola yes please

Comment: I have written an answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

To use different template for different cells you want to use DataTemplateSelector, it's documented here: [Creating a Xamarin.Forms DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector)

First define it in separate class:

```
public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate ValidTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate InvalidTemplate { get; set; }

  protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
  {
    return ((Person)item).DateOfBirth.Year >= 1980 ? ValidTemplate : InvalidTemplate;
  }
}
```

Then add it to your page's resources:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Selector;assembly=Selector" x:Class="Selector.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="validPersonTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                   ...
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="invalidPersonTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                   ...
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:PersonDataTemplateSelector x:Key="personDataTemplateSelector"
                ValidTemplate="{StaticResource validPersonTemplate}"
                InvalidTemplate="{StaticResource invalidPersonTemplate}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
  ...
</ContentPage>
```

And then just use it in your list:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource personDataTemplateSelector}" />
```

To have a possibility to expand/hide the cells, you need to:

- add a property IsExpanded to the ViewModel of specific list item
- change it to true/false on the ItemSelected event of your list
- bind the visibility of the view you want to hide/expand to the value of IsExpanded

Comment: don't hesitate to ask if you have some problems regarding these templates and remember to mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

**XAML**

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YOUR_SOURCE}" SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
             HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="MyList_ItemSelected"> 
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                <Frame>
                   <StackLayout>
                      <Label Text="My Heading"/>
                   </StackLayout>

                   <StackLayout x:Name="moreItemStack" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                IsVisible="false">
                       <Label Text="child 1"/>
                       <Label Text="child 2"/>
                   </StackLayout>
               </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView>
```

**C#**

```
  private void MyList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      var myItem = e.SelectedItem; 
      moreItemStack.IsVisible = true;          
  }
```

@user3932639 There you go

NOTE: This was written for clarification, it has been tested.